# Data inheritance with dictionaries

Tags: .net, f#, f#-3.0

I have a message that is being passed around with a property bag (a .Net dictionary) that contains some state values. Now scoping has been added, so there can be a child property bag too. I am trying to get a clean method that will look-up the state parameter from the property bags using the child first, otherwise falling back to the parent property bag.

I have a working solution, but it seems like this should be better and more clear. Can you recommend an improvement?

```
let private _fetchParameter (parameter : Parameters) (name : string) =
   let success, value = parameter.TryGetValue(name)
   match success with
   | true -> Some(value) 
   | false -> None

let internal _deepFetchParameter (child: Parameters) (parent: Parameters) (name : string) =
    let foundValue = 
        match _fetchParameter child name with
        | Some x -> Some x
        | None -> _fetchParameter parent name 

    match foundValue with
    | Some x -> x
    | None -> invalidArg name (sprintf "Could not find parameter named %s in parameters or event." name)

// an example usage
let configSetting1 = _deepFetchParameter child parent "ConfigSetting1"
```

Few minor notes:

- I realize throwing exceptions is not idiomatic F#, but this is interacting with some standard .net, and throwing an exception is the correct action in this case. (The rest of the app would throw an exception here and I want to be consistent).
- I believe there may be a better way to represent data-inheritance/data-scoping in F#, but that is a separate question I am asking on this site. My intent with this question is to improve my understanding of F# and functional design.
- Parameters is a type that is an alias for the standard .Net `dictionary<T,U>` typed to a `<string, string>`
- Suggestions on altering or abstracting away the data storage is fine, as long as you can suggest a way to merge the dictionaries.

Comment: It's not that throwing exceptions is not "idiomatic" in F#, it essentially creates a partial function, with the same consequences regardless of the language you're using. In this case a partial function is undesirable, be it F#, C#, VBNET, Java, C++ or PHP.

Comment: This would be better on codereview.se

Comment: Never heard of that until now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take a crack at this:

```
let internal _deepFetchParameter (child: Parameters) (parent: Parameters) (name : string) =
    let childFetch = _fetchParameter child
    let parentFetch = _fetchParameter parent

    match (childFetch name),(parentFetch name) with
    | Some(x), _ -> x
    | None, Some(x) -> x
    | _ -> invalidArg name (sprintf "Could not find parameter named %s in parameters or event." name)
```